# Ruler equation example

Tags: geometry

I am having trouble understanding this example in my book. First let me define ruler:

Let $l$ be a line in an incidence geometry. Assume that there is a distance function $d$. A function $f: l \to \mathbb{R}$ is a ruler for $l$ if $f$ is a bijection and for each pair of points $P$ and $Q$ on $l$ we have $|f(P) - f(Q)| = d(P,Q)$. Where $f(P)$ is called the coordinate of $P$ with respect to $f$.

**The example:** Let $l$ be the nonvertical line $L_{2,3}$ in the Cartesian Plane with Euclidean distance. Show that if $Q = (x,y)$ then $f(Q) = \sqrt{5}x$ gives a ruler $f$ for $l$ and find the coordinate of $R = (1,5)$ with respect to $f$.

**Solution:** Note that $(x,y) \in L_{2,3}$ iff $y = 2x+3$ so that if $P = (x_1, y_1)$ then $d(P,Q) = \sqrt{(x_1 - x)^2 + (y_1 - y)^2} = \sqrt{(x_1 - x)^2 +4(x_1 - x)^2} = \sqrt{5}|x_1 - x| = |f(P)- f(Q)|.$

Thus the ruler equation holds. And the coordinate of $R = (1,5)$ is $f(R) = \sqrt{5}$.

I don't know how they got those solutions?

Comment: Which aspect of the solution is it that you don't understand? They reminded you of a definition, took the two sides of the equation $d(P,Q)=\lvert f(P)-f(Q)\rvert$ and rewrote them to show that they are indeed equal, then plugged $R$ into $f$ to compute its coordinate according to the definition. Seems all very straight-forward to me.

Comment: @MvG I don't understand how they got $\sqrt{(x_1 - x)^2 +4(x_1 - x)^2} = \sqrt{5}|x_1 - x|$ and $f(R) = \sqrt{5}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how they got $\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+4(x_1-x)^2}=\sqrt5\lvert x_1-x\rvert$

$$\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+4(x_1-x)^2}
=\sqrt{5(x_1-x)^2}
=\sqrt{5}\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2}
=\sqrt5\lvert x_1-x\rvert$$

> and $f(R)=\sqrt5$.

For $R=(1,5)$ you have $x=1$ and $y=5$, which you plug into $f(R)=\sqrt5x$ to obtain $f(R)=\sqrt5\cdot1=\sqrt5$.

> I don't understand how they got $\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+4(x_1-x)^2}$ from $\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+(y_1-y)^2}$

Apparently you somewhere have a definition for lines from which you can conclude

$$L_{2,3}:=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\;\middle|\;y=2x+3\right\}$$

I don't believe this notation to be very common, but I might be wrong. From that you get

\begin{gather*}
\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+(y_1-y)^2}
=\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+\bigl((2x_1+3)-(2x+3)\bigr)^2} \\
=\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+\bigl((2x_1+3)-(2x+3)\bigr)^2}
=\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+\bigl(2(x_1-x)\bigr)^2} \\
=\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+2^2(x_1-x)^2}
=\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+4(x_1-x)^2}
\end{gather*}

Comment: Thanks but I should have specified I don't understand how they got $\sqrt{(x_1-x)^2+4(x_1-x)^2}$ from $\sqrt{(x_1 - x)^2 + (y_1 - y)^2}$?

Comment: @Alex: Then you really should put more effort in asking the right questions! Updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry! And thank you very much!